# Backbone code not rendering simple View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Simple backbone View is not rendering inside of the element, and there are no errors

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.9/backbone-min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.container',
                initialize: function() {
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function() {
                    $(this.el).html("hello"); //tried both but not working. 
                    this.$el.html("hello"); 
                } 
             }); 
             var search_view = new SearchView();
        </script>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The reason why it's not working is just because the DOM wasn't ready before the script was executed.  
7 downvotes? Takes just as long to put the answer here...

Comment: I recommend you start with this http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/11/backbone-dot-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started

Comment: you guys could help him ask the question too... @KimGysen +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you're not waiting for the DOM to be ready, try moving the div like this (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/68gGS/)

```
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.container',
            initialize: function() {
                this.render();
            },
            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html("hello"); //tried both but not working. 
                this.$el.html("hello"); 
            } 
         }); 
         var search_view = new SearchView();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Or one of the variants of `$(document).ready(function() { var search_view = new SearchView() }`. Might be a good idea to recommend that the OP upgrade to the latest jQuery, Underscore, and Backbone too.